# Objective C : Notification Service Extension getting crash on iPhone 6S or Newer Device but working below iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have created an iOS Notification Service Extension and It was working properly previously on all devices even on iPhone 6s and 6S+. But suddenly from some time ago, it is now crashing on iPhone 6S or Newer device in all iOS version tested on iOS 11 and 12 both. We can say it is crashing on iPhones in which 3d touch available. and the debugger says issue in memory allocation issue 12 MB allowed and it is allocating more than 12 MB. But the same App is working fine in iPhone 6S or older device in all iOS version tested on iOS 11 and 12 both.

**NotificationService.h**

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

API_AVAILABLE(ios(10.0))
@interface NotificationService : UNNotificationServiceExtension <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end
```

**NotificationService.m**

```
#import "NotificationService.h"

@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {

    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"Here I want to modify my payload title but app crashes before \"didReceiveNotificationRequest\" called and allocing more than 12 MB memory on iPhone 6S or Newer Device");

}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    //    [self.downloadTask cancel];
    NSLog(@"serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire");
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}
```

Can anybody let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: blocks should be copied and not strongly retained.  I don't know what problems it causes if you use `strong` instead of `copy`, but it might be the cause of your issues.

Comment: @JonRose this is system generated `strong` property I've not changed it and some time ago the same code was working fine even if I creating a new project for another app it's working fine.